# Can someone explain how this truth table was filled in from a Mealy model?

Tags: digital-logic

[image]

I'm having a bit of trouble figuring out how the truth table was filled in. I understand how to draw the diagram from the first table and I understand the boolean expression given from the truth table but I can't quite grasp how the truth table was filled in. Could anyone do me a favor and explain it for me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way the truth table was filled is the following:
You make a list of all the possible states and inputs, in this case A-D in with their respective mapping and X either 0 or 1 for this case. This should cover columns y1,y2 and X.
Then we reference the first table, Which tells me that for State A[y1=0,y2=0]and X=0, my next state should be D[Y1=1,Y2=1] and my output Z, and so on and so forth until you go through all the possible states and input combinations

Comment: So for the first row: [y1=0, y2=0] is A. The input value is x (0). Since we have A with an input of 0 we go to D which is [y1=1,y2=1] which gives us an output of 0? Essentially it is just a long-hand version of the first table?

Comment: yup, you got it... And yeah the truth table is simply an expanded version of the first table